# No puedo eliminar un like de un post

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

Estoy intentando mediante la api en `node` eliminar un registro de la tabla `likes`. Envio los argumentos a la url con `axios` como: `axios.delete(/likes, objeto, headers)` al igual que con el metodo de crear likes pero es en `deleteLike` que no me toma en back. Sin embargo por front me retorna un `403` ya que el middleware no toma el token. No se porque createLike en back me toma y llama a la funcion pero no delete.

Front:

```
// React
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// Mui like icons
import FavoriteBorderIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FavoriteBorder';
import FavoriteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Favorite';

// Axios
import axios from 'axios';

// React-cookies
import cookies from "js-cookie";

const LikeButton = (props) => {
  const { post } = props;

  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(false);
  const [numberOfLikes, setNumberOfLikes] = useState(post.total_likes);
  
  const createLike = async(post) => {

    const headers = {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'auth-token': cookies.get('auth-token')
    };

    const like = {
      post_id: post.id
    }
    
    let numLikes = parseInt(post.total_likes);
    numLikes += 1;
    console.log(numLikes)
    try {
      await axios.post('/likes', like, {headers: headers});
      setIsLiked(true);
      setNumberOfLikes(numLikes);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  const deleteLike = async(post) => {
    console.log('deleting ...')
    const headers = {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'auth-token': cookies.get('auth-token')
    }

    const like = {
      post_id: post.id,
      email: post.created_by
    }

    let numLikes = parseInt(post.total_likes);
    numLikes -= 1;

    try {
      await axios.delete('/likes', like, {headers: headers});
      setIsLiked(false);
      setNumberOfLikes(numLikes);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  return(
    (post.total_likes > 0 || isLiked) ? 
      <>
      <FavoriteIcon 
      sx={{marginLeft: '10px', fill: 'red', cursor: 'pointer'}}
      onClick={() => deleteLike(post)}
      />
      <p>{numberOfLikes}</p>
      </>
      :
      <FavoriteBorderIcon 
      sx={{marginLeft: '10px', fill: 'red', cursor: 'pointer'}}
      onClick={() => createLike(post)}
      /> 
  )
}

export default LikeButton;
```

Back:

```
const pool = require('../db');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const createLike = async(req, res, next) => {
  const { post_id } = req.body;
  console.log('creating like ----------------------------------- >')
  const token = req.headers['auth-token'];
  if(!token) return res.status(403).send('Access Denied');

  const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
  const userId = decodedToken && decodedToken.uid;

  // try {
  //   const like = await pool.query('insert into likes (user_id, post_id) values ($1, $2)', [userId, post_id]);
  //   return res.json(like.rows[0]);
  // } catch (err) {
  //   next(err);
  // }
}

const deleteLike = async(req, res, next) => {
  console.log('-----------------------> DELETE CALLED')
  const { post_id, email } = req.body;
  console.log('post_id', post_id);
  console.log('email', email);
  console.log('req', req.headers);

  const userId = await pool.query('select * from users where email = $1', [email])
  const postId = post_id;

  // try {
  //   await pool.query('delete from likes where user_id=$1 and post_id = $2', [userId.rows[0].id, postId]);
  // } catch (error) {
  //   res.json({message: 'Like not found'});
  // }
}

module.exports = {
  createLike,
  deleteLike
}
```

Rutas para likes:

```
const { Router } = require('express');

const router = Router();

const {
  createLike,
  deleteLike
} = require('../controllers/like.controller');

const { verifyTokenAuthorization } = require('../middleware/auth');

router.post('/likes', verifyTokenAuthorization, createLike);
router.delete('/likes', verifyTokenAuthorization, deleteLike);


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la [documentación de axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro), el método `delete` recibe sólo dos parámetros: la `url` y opcionalmente la configuración (`config`):

> axios.delete(url[, config])

Pero tu en tu código lo estás llamando con 3 parámetros, es por ello que no te funciona. Nota que tu tercer parámetro son las cabeceras, que por supuesto, nunca llegan.

En orden de solucionar tu problema, por favor, refactoriza el código a:

```
await axios.delete('/likes', {
    headers: headers,
    data: like
});
```

Comment: gracias estimado.